# Return a variable from inside a lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I have a method that receives a dto in which many of its fields are used to make a dynamic query based on the non-null fields.
I am accessing each field by reflection in a lambda to add the non-null fields to the dynamic query. This works, but I don't know how to get that list to return it.

```
@Override 
     public List<AirlinePreOrderDto> getPreorders(AirlinePreOrderDto airlinePreOrderDto) {
        
            PreOrder entity = PreOrderMapper.mapToJpaEntity(airlinePreOrderDto);
        
            Query dynamicQuery = new Query();   
                    
            ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(entity.getClass(), field -> {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    if (field.get(entity) != null) {
                        if (!field.getName().equals("serialVersionUID")) {
                            if(field.getName().equals("preorderId")) {
                                dynamicQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where(field.getName()).is(field.get(entity)));
                            } else {
                                dynamicQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where(field.getName()).is(field.get(entity)));
                            }
                        }
                        List<AirlinePreOrderDto> result = PreOrderMapper
                                .mapToDtos(mongoTemplate.find(dynamicQuery, PreOrder.class, "preorders"));
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
    
          // return result list;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use an enclosing class.

```
       class EnclosingResults {
            List<AirlinePreOrderDto> results;
            
            public void setResults(List<AirlinePreOrderDto> results) {
                this.results = results;
            }
            public List<AirlinePreOrderDto> getResults() {
                return results;
            }
        }
```

So your method will be:

```
        @Override 
        public List<AirlinePreOrderDto> getPreorders(AirlinePreOrderDto airlinePreOrderDto) {
       
           PreOrder entity = PreOrderMapper.mapToJpaEntity(airlinePreOrderDto);
       
           Query dynamicQuery = new Query();  
           
           EnclosingResults resultEncloser = new EnclosingResults();
                   
           ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(entity.getClass(), field -> {
               field.setAccessible(true);
               try {
                   if (field.get(entity) != null) {
                       if (!field.getName().equals("serialVersionUID")) {
                           if(field.getName().equals("preorderId")) {
                               dynamicQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where(field.getName()).is(field.get(entity)));
                           } else {
                               dynamicQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where(field.getName()).is(field.get(entity)));
                           }
                       }
                       List<AirlinePreOrderDto> result = PreOrderMapper
                               .mapToDtos(mongoTemplate.find(dynamicQuery, PreOrder.class, "preorders"));
                       resultEncloser.setResults(result);
                   }
               } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           });
   
         return resultEncloser.getResults()
       }
```

Comment: That's a reasonable approach in general, but I don't think it matches the intended behaviour of this method.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't want to call `mongoTemplate.find` or `PreOrderMapper.mapToDtos` inside of the lambda, as the lambda will be executed *once for each local field*.

But from your code I'd guesstimate that you really want to execute the query after having built the `dynamicQuery` object from *all fields*.

And since you already manipulate the object referenced by `dynamicQuery` inside the lambda, it's as simple as moving the code to actually *execute* it out of the lambda:

```
        PreOrder entity = PreOrderMapper.mapToJpaEntity(airlinePreOrderDto);
    
        Query dynamicQuery = new Query();   
                
        ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(entity.getClass(), field -> {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                if (field.get(entity) != null) {
                    if (!field.getName().equals("serialVersionUID")) {
                        if(field.getName().equals("preorderId")) {
                            dynamicQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where(field.getName()).is(field.get(entity)));
                        } else {
                            dynamicQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where(field.getName()).is(field.get(entity)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        List<AirlinePreOrderDto> result = PreOrderMapper
               .mapToDtos(mongoTemplate.find(dynamicQuery, PreOrder.class, "preorders"));
        return result;
```